# Compare 2 numbers in x8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'd like to get some help with my assembly studying process.
I have to write a program that compares 2 numbers and stores the lowest one in AL and the highest one in BL. I'm using EMU8086 emulator in Windows 10 64-bit

Thank you sincerely for your help!

Actually I don't have an idea how to make this work, so i'm looking for any help

Comment: Load both numbers into registers `AL` and `BL` with `MOV`. Compare them with `CMP AL,BL` . If `AL` is below `BL`, you are done: `JB Done`, otherwise `XCHG AL,BL`.

Comment: Are numbers signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
ORG 0100H

NUMBER1 EQU 78
NUMBER2 EQU 25

MOV AL,NUMBER1  ; STORE NUMBER1 VALUE IN (AL)
MOV BL,NUMBER2  ; STORE NUMBER2 VALUE IN (BL)

CMP AL,BL       ; COMPARE (AL) REGISTER AND (BL) REGISTER
JB STOP         ; IF (AL) IS LESS THAN (BL) EXIT FROM PROGRAM

XCHG AL,BL      ; OTHERWISE EXCHANGE VALUES OF TWO REGISTERS

STOP:

RET
```

Comment: Just from reading this, it works, but it would be a good idea to actually show the output. Which is a bit tricky if you're new to assembly.